# Array of [String][1] type in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a set of values of the following form:

```
{"a" "string 1", "a"}
{"b" "string 2", "b"}
{"c" "string n", "a"}
```

EDIT: If I declare an array like char foo[][/*charactersOfString*/][/*specianUniqueCharacter*/], and the third dimension only uses one of the columns, there would exist not required positions that would imply wasting a lot of memory space ([0][0][1] should not exist. [0][0][0] or [1][2][0] should exist).

How can I solve this problem without using a structure or appending the content of column 3 to the end of column 2?

Comment: What do you mean by *only the first character of each element will be used*? Are they string literals in the real code?

Comment: You don't have a single question in your text. What is the issue here? Please edit and clarify.

Comment: @user1920212 Also it is not clear whether the strings have the same size.

Comment: Efficiency of a structure depends on its major usage case. This is why we have arrays, lists, trees... What is your major use-case for the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array of string pointers is quite typical (it's the same type as the second parameter of `main()`).

```
const char *stuff[][2] = {
    {"string 1", "a"},
    {"string 2", "b"},
    {"string n", "a"}
};
```

The difference here is I have marked the contents as `const` because we are saving pointers to string literals: this is allowed, but modifying string literals is not, so the `const` is there for safety.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply assume first character of string for second value and has simple array of strings (char pointers):

```
"astring 1"
"bstring 2"
"astring n"
```

If your array is `char ** str` you will access `a` and `b` values as `str[n][0]` and other like `str[n] + 1`.